# Intel VT-x not available on Windows 10 so HAXM is not working for android

Tags: windows-10, intel, virtualization, haxm

I have an **Intel Core i5 6400** CPU installed on **ASUS Z-170A** mainboard. According to the documentation of my [CPU](https://ark.intel.com/products/88185/Intel-Core-i5-6400-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3-30-GHz-), this CPU support Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-X).  I have **Windows 10 Pro** on my PC and using `Intel(R) Processor Identification Utility` by Intel and it reports that my CPU does not support VT-X.

This caused so many problems such as I cannot install HAXM for Android on my CPU due to lack of VT-X.  I should notice that *I've enabled VT-x on my BIOS* settings.  I also checked that **memory integrity** is disabled in my windows defender settings.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable VT-x besides of enabling it in BIOS, uses should [Disable Windows Defender Credential Guard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/credential-guard/credential-guard-manage)  as below:

1. Run `gpedit.msc` and then go to:

`Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System -> Device Guard -> Turn on Virtualization Based Security`

and select `Disabled` option.

2. Then run `regedit` and delete these keys if they are present in registery:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\LSA\LsaCfgFlags
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DeviceGuard\EnableVirtualizationBasedSecurity
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DeviceGuard\RequirePlatformSecurityFeatures

3. Execute `cmd` as administrator and run below command to enable NX bit:

> bcdedit.exe /set {current} nx AlwaysOn

4. For me, the magic part was this. run `regedit` and in folder:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\DeviceGuard\Scenarios\HypervisorEnforcedCodeIntegrity

set `Enabled` to  0.

Here is the result:
[image]

P.S. Great thanks to Ulises2k for his/her answer at https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/8004c3bd-7d57-40ce-93de-0b1a6babd64c/how-i-can-disable-credential-guard?forum=win10itprovirt which helped me for part 4 of this answer.